# fragment remove issue

Tags: java, android, fragment

I am just learning fragments today. I press a button and it adds/removes a fragment. However if I try remove the fragment every fragment apart from the one I want removed is removed, why? The first press correctly adds a fragment.

```
Button2 fragment:

 Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

              ButtonFragment fragment = new ButtonFragment();
              if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()) {



                  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

                  FragmentTransaction transaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
                  transaction.remove(fragment).commit();

              }
              else if(!fragment.isVisible())
              {
                  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

                  FragmentTransaction transaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
                  transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment ).commit();
  }       

          }
        });
        return view;
      }
}
```

I have two fragments like this in xml: 
When I click the button I want the fragment not defined in xml to be added, and it is.
However the next time i press the button, which should remove that fragment. Everything is removed apart from that fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#123456"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"  >


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/TimeFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.myfragment.TimeFragment" >
        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
    </fragment>



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/Button2Fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.myfragment.Button2Fragment" >
        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post the stack trace - it makes it easier to find the problem

Comment: added it now, thanks. Seems the trace is different now so i must have changed things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant remove a `Framgnet` that you have added using the XML. If you want to remove the fragment via the `.remove` method you should first add it to your layout via the `.add` method, and not embed it into the XML file. in this case you can only `.show` or `.hide` the `Fragments`.

**UPDATE:**

To add the `ButtonFragment` dynamically do this:

```
ButtonFragment buttonsFragment = new ButtonFragment();
newfragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
newfragmentTransaction.add(R.id.containerForFragments, buttonsFragment ).commit();
```

**UPDATE 2:**
This code:

```
  Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

          ButtonFragment fragment = new ButtonFragment();
          if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()) {



              FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

              FragmentTransaction transaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
              transaction.remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.layout.activity_main)).commit();

          }
          else if(!fragment.isVisible())
          {
              FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

              FragmentTransaction transaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
              transaction.add(R.layout.activity_main, fragment ).commit();
          }       

      }
    });
```

should be run from the `Activity` and not from the `Fragment`.

Comment: If I don't add it in xml, how do i accomplish the same thing? Because I can't use  `ButtonFragment fragment = (ButtonFragment) getFragmentManager()
                  .findFragmentById(R.id.ButtonFragment); 
        boolean a = true;
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()) {`

Comment: thanks, but what goes here `R.id.containerForFragments` I cant say R.id.ButtonFragment as it;s removed from the xml

Comment: instead of the R.id.containerForFragments, put the layout id where you want to place your Fragment.

Comment: I had tried R.layout.activity_main but that didnt work, ill try other things thanks

Comment: I edited to show the issue. R.layout.activity_main is my main activity where the fragments are located

Comment: Hi, yes this is the code I already have. I tried changing R.layout.activity_main to fragment_container via  android:id="@+id/fragment_container" and my backtrace disappears. The first thing that happens when I press the button is the button gets added correctly. Next time I press the button, the button i press disappears, as does every other fragment apart from the one I want to, which stays there.

Comment: completely changed question in post

Comment: have you read my edit to the end? I wrote to you that the code of switching fragment should be run from the Activity and not from the fragment.

Comment: I dont know how I didnt see that, thanks will try that. Have to figure out where view comes from, as it was inflated in the fragment.