# Add Fragments in xml or programmatically?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am wondering is there any reason to do one over the other. I have been adding fragments via xml and using show/hide. I wanted to learn about replace/add/remove so I tried to add them programmatically. This has led to problems [fragment remove issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359993/fragment-remove-issue) and just seems less straight forward to me.

It also seems easy to place them via xml, whilst I'm still not sure how to programatically (as you don't have a reference to the fragment in the xml of the view that youa re adding it to?).  Is there any reason for me to add fragments programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fragments added in XML cannot be replaced or removed, other than that major limitation choose whichever method is easiest for you.

Comment: Ah I see thank you, they are always there even though they are hidden. So if I don't want to use one a lot I should use it programatically. Makes sense, thanks.